# How can I update Tclsh in linux?

Tags: linux, tcl, tclsh

I work with Linux Red-Hat 2.4 
and probably have an old version of tclsh, how can I update it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to get an up-to-date and complete Tcl installation is to download the community edition of ActiveTcl from [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl).

Comment: While SO is not normally in the business of product recommendations, in the case of Tcl, the ActiveTcl distribution is *definitely* the best fully-curated distro; they've got a real expert on building that sort of thing on staff.